# RShiny - how to update a rhansontable depending on connected users

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

I'm working on a R Shiny application in which I build a Handsontable datatable (package `rhansontable`). This table both can be updated by a user and exported as a CSV file (it means that if a user changes the CSV, the exported file will keep the modifications).
All is ok on this first step.

Now I want to associate the Handsontable datatable with my PostgreSQL database. The process would be this one :

1. a user is connecting to the app
2. the user is connected and the app will get his ID
3. the app uses this ID to get his specific data in the database
4. the user can see his data in the Handsontable datatable

I use Shiny Dashboard and the auth process works well (that is to say 1. and 2.).
But the whole process fails. It seems the app crashes because the ID (parameter `iduser`) would not be reactive. The error is described below :

> Warning: Error in $: Can't access reactive value 'iduser' outside of
> reactive consumer. ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or
> observe()?
> 53:  Error in res_auth$iduser :   Can't
> access reactive value 'iduser' outside of reactive consumer. ℹ Do you
> need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?

How could I do to make the ID parameter reactive and to use it with RHandsontable ?

Here is the part of my code concerned :

**ui.R**

```
rHandsontableOutput("table", height= '200px'),
actionButton(inputId="saveBtn",label="Export to CSV", class = "btn btn-success")
```

**server.R**

```
   # Create dataframe with user credentials from the database (here only the final dataframe is shown)
        credentials  <- tibble::tibble(
          user = users,
          password = password,
          iduser = iduser
        )
    
    # Get the ID of the connected user
        res_auth <- secure_server(
            check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
        )
      
        output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
            reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
          
        idUserConnected <- res_auth$iduser
    
    
     # Try to build a reactive datatable depending on the ID User
     
        dbdata <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste0("select name, job, salary from users where iduser =" , idUserConnected, ";"))
        df = dbdata
        datavalues <- reactiveValues(data=df)   
    
        # Create the datatable
        output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
           rhandsontable(datavalues$data, width = 800) %>%
           hot_table(highlightRow = TRUE, highlightCol = TRUE) %>%
           hot_cols(colWidths=c(50, 150, 150, 55, 55))
        })
    
        # If any changes in the table
        observeEvent(
          input$table$changes$changes, # observe if any changes to the cells of the rhandsontable
          {
            datavalues$data <- hot_to_r(input$table) # convert the rhandontable to R data frame object so manipulations / calculations could be done
            }
        )
    
    # Export CSV Button to export datatable updated in CSV
       saveData <- function(){
          list <- hot_to_r(input$table)
          df <- as.data.frame(list)
          df <- df[ , c("name", "job", "salary")]
          write.csv(df, "output.csv", row.names = FALSE)
        }
        
        observeEvent(
          input$saveBtn, 
          saveData()
        )
```

Could you help me on this part ? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: From your code, which is not reproducible, I can tell that at least `iduser = iduser` is generating that error message ond the right hand value. How are you accesing that value?